# habilitar cors headers en laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

tuve este problema al tratar de consumir una API en laravel desde react:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://apirest.com/companies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled
```

Encontre información y tengo una duda como agrego la ruta del end point http://apirest.com/register y http://apirest.com/companies al archivo routes? usé este codigo para laravel 6:

archivo cors.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
       //Url a la que se le dará acceso en las peticiones
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://urlfronted.example")
      //Métodos que a los que se da acceso
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
      //Headers de la petición
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"); 
  }
}
```

kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  ...,
  ...,
  "cors" => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
 ];
```

el codigo que hay que usar en el archivo de rutas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    //Rutas a las que se permitirá acceso
});
```

mi arhcivo de rutas web.php:

```
Route::resource('/','ClientsController');
Route::resource('/register','ClientsController');
Route::resource('/companies','CompaniesController');
```

archivo de rutas api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: ahí dejé el código

Comment: Y las rutas cuales son? Solo mustras las urls...  ¿Probaste ponerlas dentro del grupo que tiene aplicado el middleware?

Comment: la urls son virtuales en mi host, cual es el codigo para agregarlas? son peticiones a una api POST. GET, PUT, DELETE

Comment: Ok edite el post

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105173/discussion-between-user2820116-and-porloscerros-).